# Changing images using for loop

Tags: android, image, loops

How to change an image to the next one in the array using a for loop, once a button has been clicked. At present I have this in my on click method.

```
 int[] Pics = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3};

 for (int i=0; i<Pics.length; i++){

     mainpic.setImageResource(Pics[i]);

 }
```

The problem is when the next button is clicked, it only stays at the first image or goes straight through to the last image.

Comment: because you should do it in the background and put delay every image chages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i quite dont get it ... you wrote that when you click the next button for **next image** its not working ... but what is not working ? this is **for loop** ... it will loop to the end of an array and set the image to the **last image** in it... what you need to define a class variable like

```
int[] Pics = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3};
int i = 0;
mainpic.setImageResource(Pics[i]);
```

then inside next button **onClick** method ..

```
 i++;
 if(i >=3) {
   i = 0;
 }
 mainpic.setImageResource(Pics[i]);
```

Comment: this works perfect for looping through the images but give an out of bounds error when an intent is set at the if rather than i=0. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

try this block of code you are missing new int[]

```
int[] Pics = new int[]{R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3};
```

and use this inside of loop

```
int i = 0;
```

**onClick** method

```
mainpic.setImageResource(Pics[i]);
i++
```

Comment: thats not true ... you should read the ways how you can declare arrays in java ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java

Comment: ok you are right we have two ways of declaring arrays int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};

Answer (score 0):

You do not need for loop for this. Handle image change in onClick():

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
      if (view.getId() == R.id.<ButtonId>)
      {
           mainpic.setImageResource(Pics[currentImageIndex]);
           currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % Pics.Length;
      }
}
```

PS: currentImageIndex is a class variable. The `%` operation will allow you to change the image in a cyclic fashion.